# How can I ensure references appear in the order of appearance in my manuscript for the Oxford Complex Networks Journal?

Tags: citing, bibliographystyle

I am working on a manuscript for the Oxford Complex Networks Journal and attempting to generate references in the order of appearance. However, the current references are not following the desired order. How can I address this issue? I am using the provided class file, and the associated .bst file is 'comnet.bst.' Here is the link to the class file:

https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/comnet/document/Template-for-Journal-of-Complex-Networks%2528COMNET%2529.zip?node=ea0097afa8960a88b78b&version=495322:4df78c5c17411b53a9de.

What steps should I take to ensure that references are ordered correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's not clear to me why you don't want to accept the default method specified by the scholarly journal of interest. Put differently, why is the bibliography style (bst) file the journal provides not good enough for you? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico it seems the journal itself mandates references in the order of appearance, see https://academic.oup.com/comnet/pages/General_Instructions: "In the text, references should be numbered consecutively with citation numbers in square brackets, for example [1] or [2,5-7]". This _might_ mean that within one set of brackets the numbers should be consecutive (so [9,5-7] would not be allowed), but probably it means that the references should be in order of appearance and therefore the bst file does not implement the journal's own author guidelines.

Comment: @Mico I want like this: Things work this way [1] but we want like [2]. But the manuscript is as: Things work this way [15] but we want like [9]. The journal also expects the former. But their provided .bst file generates the later.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assume that their template does what they want. Ask them for clarification if you are unsure but do not patch their code or change their bst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562312) shows how to modify a given `.bst` bibstyle file so that references are listed in order of appearance. The idea is that this is actually the *default* order they’ll be written in unless the bibstyle sorts them, so you find wherever the bibstyle file sorts them, which will be a few lines something like

```
ITERATE {presort}

SORT
```

and then comment out those lines:

```
%%% % modified to leave refs unsorted
%%% ITERATE {presort}
%%%
%%% SORT
```

The exact lines you need to comment may depend on the bibstyle file you’re modifying, but in almost all cases it will be something recognisably similar to this. For this specific `comnet.bst`, Mico and SDGAL note in comments that the relevant lines seem to be 987–989, 1024, and 1043–1045 (each either an `ITERATE` or a `SORT`).

It’s good practice to also rename the style file (to e.g. `comnet-mod.bst`) and add a comment line at the top of the file noting its modifications,

```
%%% modified by SGDAL on 2024-01-08 to leave refs in order of appearance, following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706542
```

so that anyone else handling your source (including yourself in a few years) doesn’t confuse it with the unmodified version.

Comment: The answer you've found isn't quite right. The file `comnet.bst` has not one but two instances (cf. lines 987 to 989, and 1043 to 1045) of `ITERATE` followed immediately by `SORT`. Both instances should be commented out.

Comment: @Mico Thanks — have edited that into the answer!

Comment: @Mico ITERATE {forward.pass}  at line 1024 needs to be commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Ok. I have got the answer. Just one more line. One more edit is needed in the comnet.bst file.

ITERATE {forward.pass} at line 1024 also has to be commented out besides the lines 987, 989, 1043 and 1045.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).